# GNU C Compiler is not working on QT Creator for OSX

Tags: qt, gcc, clang

I installed `gcc` on OSX via `brew`. I need to use gcc instead of clang for a specific command which clang does not support. In shell screen, `gcc example.c` command compiles example.c code with clang whereas `gcc-9 example.c` command compiles the code with the original gcc (GNU C Compiler).

In QT, I need to use `pipe()` function to get output of a GCC command. If I put a command string with gcc to the pipe function, it gives error because clang does not support the specific command I mentioned about in the beginning. If I put a command with gcc-9 to the pipe function, this time QT gives error like "gcc-9: not found".

Why does `gcc-9` command works on shell screen but not in QT? How can I use `gcc-9` command in QT?

The code piece is below:

```
std::string removeComments(const std::string &path)
{
    std::array <char, 256> buffer;
    std::string result, cmd = "gcc-9 -fpreprocessed -dD -E '" + path + "'";
    std::unique_ptr <FILE, decltype(&pclose)> pipe(popen(cmd.c_str(), "r"), pclose);

    if (!pipe)
        throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");

    fgets(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), pipe.get());

    while (fgets(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), pipe.get()) != nullptr)
        if (!skipLine(buffer.data()))
            result += buffer.data();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: How did you configure gcc-9 in the Qt Creator “Kit" that you’re using? The error suggests it’s probably just not found, your shell might have it in the PATH and Qt creator might have not.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Screenshoot is here: https://i.imgur.com/kFzrkWW.png
I set the path of "Linux ICC" as "/usr/local/bin/gcc-9" where gcc-9 is installed. But it still not working.

Comment: "clang does not support the specific command I mentioned about in the beginning" What command?

Comment: ICC is not GCC and Linux is not Mac OS.

Comment: @n.m. it's `gcc -fpreprocessed`, I use this to remove comments from C source files.
Isn't ICC is just name of the compiler? I set the path of the ICC as path of gcc-9. Here is the screenshoot: https://i.imgur.com/yNWTCc1.png (I'm sorry, I've never used OSX before, and I'm using Hackintosh right now. So I don't know what ICC is.)

Comment: No, ICC is a totally different compiler.

Comment: It isn't clear what exactly is not working in Qt and what error messages you are getting. "If I put a command with gcc-9 to the pipe function" --- what does this mean exactly? how do you put it in the function? where's the code?

Comment: @n.m. I added the code piece to the question description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler you are using to compile your code has nothing to do with the compiler you are trying to call *from* your code. None of the compiler settings in your IDE are relevant. To avoid confusion, return them to their default values.

You need to either

1. set up your `PATH` environment variable such that `/usr/local/bin` is included, and the command `gcc-9` can be found by the shell; or
2. use a *full path* like `"/usr/local/bin/gcc-9"`

Comment: Oh, how stupid I am. `/usr/local/bin/gcc-9 -fpreprocessed ...` works. Thank you.